# Returning a decimal number between 0 to 1 for showing how large each number in a set of number is

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

I hope the title does not go so far, I just want to describe what I want simply:

I have a set of random numbers, and I want to return a decimal number from 0 to 1 to show how big (max) the number is.

Imagine this *(It is just example, with not true result!)*:

**This is the set (Array):** 3580, 532, 5, 1002, 1800

**Result should be something like:** 1, 0.3, 0.05, 0.3, 0.42 *(This is just example!)*

Comment: Divide by the largest of them....?

Comment: @T.Bongers You mean should I divide all of the numbers to the largest? And How to make the result to be between 1 and 0

Comment: Something like this? N[{3580, 532, 5, 1002, 1800} / Total[{3580, 532, 5, 1002, 1800}]] == {0.517416, 0.0768897, 0.000722648, 0.144819, 0.260153}

Comment: @FredKline I'm not good mathematician (Actually I'm not at all) can you please provide more detail and simpler? sorry, thanks :)

Comment: When you divide each number by the total of all numbers, you get the percent each number is of the total. The total of the percents should be close to 100%.

Comment: Just checking, could the numbers ever be negative?

Comment: @Joffan No, It never should be negative, just from 0 to 1

Comment: @Kermani I meant the original numbers, not the result, which you were clear about in the question.

Comment: @Joffan, No, the original number also is always from 0 to positive N

Comment: You might search for "normalization" to find a method which will accomplish what you need. There are many ways to normalize.

Comment: @FredKline  If you know the answer and how to solve my problem, Please post it as an answer. Thanks, I will also read now about normalization

Comment: @Joffan posted a nice answer, showing 3 methods. If those work for you, accept the answer by checking the check mark.

Comment: @FredKline Thank you, Yes, his answer is so good and helped me to solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test set: $\{941, 421, 204, 1482, 1142, 1468, 790 \}$

Three possibilities:

1. Divide by the largest number - in the test set, $1482$. We'll always get a value $1$ in the result set. This gives values (to 3dp):

   $\{ 0.635, 0.284, 0.138, 1.000, 0.771, 0.991, 0.533  \}$
2. Divide by the sum of the set - in this case, $6448$. Then we get:

   $\{0.146, 0.065, 0.032, 0.230, 0.177, 0.228, 0.123 \}$
3. Subtract the smallest number ($204$) then divide by the resulting largest ($1278$). The results will always have a $0$ and a $1$. The test set gives:

   $\{0.577, 0.170, 0.000, 1.000, 0.734, 0.989, 0.459\}$

You might use different options in different circumstances. It could be appropriate to use these with maximum, minimum or total values that don't come from the data concerned, as well - some reference limits or total "universe" that is known separately.

Comment: Thank you, I think the first one work well for me. So nice answer :)